# Landing page on different server with same domain

Tags: wordpress, dns

I have a problem. I’m planning to transition my app landing page to WordPress living on it’s own server meanwhile my core app will be keep living on another server. Logical, right?!. Now tricky part is that I want that my new WordPress landing page will be accessible from my main domain (lets call it example.com), at the same time for my main app, I would like to keep all user links/bookmarks working (i.e I mean if user has bookmarked example.com/dashboard, I’d like that user reaches to actually app, not to WordPress site). Landing page might also serve blog and pricing and careers pages for example.

WordPress (landing) — server A — domain: example.com([/blog],[/pricing],etc..)

Core app — server B — domain: example.com/some/app/path

What is the cleverest way to achieve this?

Comment: No cleverness required - WP can co-exist on the same server as another app, although it's easiest to install it in a sub-directory and have a static HTML as your front page. Eg, install it in example.com/home and have your app in example.com/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the following steps -

1. Keep the DNS mapped to your core app server.
2. For home page, make a CURL call from your server to the wordpress, and than return the result. You can cache this call data say for every 30 mins, if its not too dynamic, otherwise you can cache it for longer period.